# (solved) equivalance relation property (homework)

Tags: real-analysis, equivalence-relations

I am taking a first class in real analysis and am stumped already. The text leaves out the steps to the following relationship and I can not connect the dots. Any explanations would be appreciated.

(m,n) $\simeq$ (p,q) and (p,q) $\simeq$ (r,s) $\Rightarrow$ (m,n) $\simeq$ (r,s)

I have no problem showing (m,n) $\simeq$ (p,q) $\Rightarrow$ (p,q) $\simeq$ (m,n)

$\ (m,n) \simeq (p,q) \Rightarrow m+q=n+p 
\Rightarrow q+m=p+n 
\Rightarrow p+n=q+m 
\Rightarrow (p,q) \simeq (m,n)$

but I can not make the next step.

Thanks for looking.

Comment: Have you heard of the transitive property of equivalence relations?

Comment: If $\simeq$ is an equivalence relation then this is one of its [defining properties](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation). Thus the statement is true by definition!

Comment: So if I can show (m,n) is equivalent to (p,q) and (p,q) is equivalent to (r,s) I can say something like: by the transitive property, (m,n) is equivalent to (r,s)?

Comment: If you already know that $\simeq$ is a equivalence relation then yes, you can do that. However, if you are to show that $\simeq$ is a equaivalence relation then no. Then you have to demonstrate that $(m,n) \simeq (r,s)$ whenever $(m,n) \simeq (p,q)$ and $(p,q) \simeq (r,s)$.

Comment: I don't think this makes any sense unless there is some specific rule defining what is meant by $(m,n)\simeq(p,q)$.  Can you provide details?

Comment: $\ (m,n) \simeq (p,q)  \Rightarrow  m+q=n+p  \Rightarrow  q+m=p+n  \Rightarrow  p+n=q+n  \Rightarrow  (p,q) \simeq (m,n)$

Comment: Please edit that into your question so that future readers can find it without having to scroll through the comments.  While you are doing that, I will answer it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that
$$(m,n)\simeq(p,q)\quad\hbox{and}\quad (p,q)\simeq(r,s)\ .$$
According to your definition this means that
$$m+q=n+p\quad\hbox{and}\quad p+s=q+r\ .$$
Adding these equations,
$$m+q+p+s=n+p+q+r\ ;$$
cancelling $q$ and $p$ gives
$$m+s=n+r\ .$$
By definition this means
$$(m,n)\simeq(r,s)\ .$$

Comment: Awesome, thank you! I couldn't see to add the two equations.